Inference of analog neural network in LTspice
I am attempting to replicate the XOR model described in the paper "Training End-to-End Analog Neural Networks with Equilibrium Propagation" using LTspice. Specifically, I am using the parameters and circuit structure provided in the paper for my simulation.
Here is my LTspice netlist:
V§X1 N001 0 -2
V§X2 N002 0 -2
V§B1 N003 0 1
D1 N004 h1_in D
D2 h1_in N006 D
V1 N004 0 -0.7
V2 N006 0 0.3
D3 N005 h2_in D
D4 h2_in N007 D
V3 N005 0 -0.7
V4 N007 0 0.3
E1 h1_out 0 h1_in 0 {A}
F1 h1_in 0 E1 {1/A}
E2 h2_out 0 h2_in 0 {A}
F2 h2_in 0 E2 {1/A}
I1 0 y_minus 0
I2 0 y_plus 0
R1 h1_in N001 10.13
R2 h1_in N002 11.63
R3 h1_in N003 79279.53
R4 h2_in N001 16.34
R5 h2_in N002 20.22
R6 h2_in N003 17.14
R7 y_minus h2_out 83.6
R8 y_minus h1_out 9.98
R9 y_plus h2_out 8.73
R10 y_plus h1_out 177.3
.model D D
.lib standard.dio
.model D D Is=1u n=2
.param A=4
.op
.backanno
.end

What I've done:

Created the model as per the description in the paper.
Ensured that the diode model corresponds to the one provided (.model D D Is=1u n=2).
Used the parameter A=4 and verified all resistor and voltage source values.

Despite my efforts, I am encountering discrepancies between my simulated voltages and the expected voltages provided in the paper.



Node
Voltage of my simulation
Expected voltage




h1_in
-1.3105
-0.79


h2_in
-0.927428
-0.74


h1_out
-5.242
-3.16


h2_out
-3.70971
-2.98


y_minus
-5.07858
-3.14


y_plus
-3.78162
-2.99



What could be causing the difference between my simulated voltages and the expected ones from the paper?

